# relocate $HOME/.cf to other location on Windows (specify custom path for .cf)

Tags: windows, client, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

My `.cf` folder is on a network mapped drive `U:\.cf`. When I am not connected to corporate network I receive this error because drive is not available. I use Windows 7

```
FAILED Error read/writing config:  open U:\.cf\config.json: This operation is supported  only when you are connected to the server.
```

I also have issues with targets plugin, because I am not owner of the folder (only read and write perms).

```
> cf save-target -f example
Error: symlink U:\.cf\targets\example.config.json U:\.cf\targets\current: A required privilege is not held by the client.
```

Howto move `.cf` to a local drive? For example `C:\.cf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/whats-new-v6.html) for the CF CLI...

*"The new CF_HOME environment variable allows you to locate the config.json file wherever you like."*

Set this shell variable to another location.